# Missing fields in responses from Office 365 RESTful API

Tags: node.js, office365, outlook-restapi

I am using node-outlook library to work with Office 365 RESTful API.
When I fetch the contacts I cannot find data for such fields as "Mobile Phone 2", "Other Phone", "Business fax", "Notes". Although they are perfectly accessible via Office 365 web GUI.
It seems to me that these fields are just not exposed through the API at all. Am I right saying that or there actually is some tricky way to access them?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

These properties aren't currently supported in Office 365 REST API as they are not commonly used.  Let us know more about the scenario, and we may be able to suggest an alternate way of implementing it.